# Python - Problema de NZEC no SPOJ (br.spoj.com)

Tags: python

Estou tentando passar um código no SPOJ (http://br.spoj.com/problems/MITO09/) para resolução de um problema bem simples: Ler uma matriz, ler coordenadas da matriz, e verificar se uma mesma coordenada foi lida duas vezes. Se sim, imprime 1. Se não, imprime 0.

Estou recebendo o erro: erro em tempo de execuçăo (NZEC).

O código:

```
import sys
import psyco
psyco.full()

def main():
    matriz = [[]]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    repetido = False
    x = 0
    y = 0
    n = 0

    #sys.stdin.readline()
    for i in range(530):
        for j in range(530):
            matriz[i].append(0)
        matriz.append([])
    del matriz[530]

    n = int(raw_input())
    for i in range(n):
        gamb = raw_input().split();
        x = int(gamb[0])
        y = int(gamb[1])
        if matriz[x][y] == 1:
            repetido = True
        else:
            matriz[x][y] = 1

    if repetido:
        print "1"
    else:
        print "0"

main()
```

O que poderia causar esse tipo de erro? Obrigado!

Comment: Note que como você está dentro de um loop a partir do primeiro que der repetido todos os demais serão considerados repetidos, sendo ou não.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece quando você tenta acessar uma posição inválida, caso hajam erros de sintaxe em conversão de tipo ou algo semelhante.

Seguem os erros mais comuns:

- http://laws.deinf.ufma.br/~marcio/ats/spoj_erros.pdf

Answer (score 0):

O erro provavelmente é esse `import psyco`. O SPOJ em geral não deixa você importar bibliotecas, com algumas poucas exceções (`sys` por exemplo). Via de regra, se você precisou baixar a biblioteca separadamente, não use.

A boa notícia é que a biblioteca não está sendo usada para nada no seu código. Você pode deletar as linhas 2 e 3 e não vai acontecer nada.

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço Python, mas em C/C++ NZEC indica que sua função main não retornou o valor 0, ou seja, em C/C++ a última instrução da função main deve ser return 0;

Ex:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  // Código
  return 0; //Solução para NZEC
}
```